# Trying to understand how MySQL license applies to code I wrote

Tags: java, licensing, gpl, mysql

I have an ERP, coded with Java and the database in MYSQL Community edition. When I was going to sell it to a client he asked me for the sources to my application (with the belief that it is GPLed). I already got an upfront payment from him.  But now he asks me to deliver the source code for my ERP with the executable.

When I told him no, he responds that as I am using MySQL community edition the project must be open source, and I must give him the sources. He is not willing pay extra for the source for what I wrote.

It doesn't seem like the MySQL license should affect the license of the code I have written.  But is that true?

Comment: Use [mariadb](https://mariadb.org/) and [download](https://downloads.mariadb.org/) the source code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that likely isn't the issue.

Comment: Ok Can I sell my java application which will connects to a MYSQL data base uding JDBC connctor,without providing the sources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The GPL does not require that you GPL license any software that connects to MySQL ([When are you required to have a commercial MySQL license?](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/02/17/when-are-you-required-to-have-a-commercial-mysql-license/)).

If you just have your database sitting there, and connect to it, and could swap out the MySQL database for MariaDB, or PostgreSQL, or Oracle, or what have you your application is not a derived work of MySQL and does not need to be GPLed.

If, on the other hand, you have embedded MySQL within your application as a single bundle (see [MySQL as an Embedded Database](http://www.mysql.com/oem/) and [Guide to MySQL as an Embedded Database](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-mysql-as-an-embedded-database/)), it does become a derivative work and your options are either to buy a commercial license for MySQL (one license choice) or be constrained by the GPL.

The above is *specifically* in context of connecting to a database.  It says nothing about the libraries or means of connecting to that database.  Note that the ConnectorJ library is under the GPL.  Linking to *that* library would make the application fall under the GPL too.  There are other connectors which may or may not have a different license that does not entail that linking application is GPL.  However, just connecting to a database that is under the GPL does not mean your application is under the GPL too.

**As always, I am not a lawyer.  If you need a lawyer, you should get one.  If this becomes an issue of contract resolution, you likely need a lawyer.**

Consider also contacting [MySQL directly](http://www.mysql.com/about/contact/) and asking for their answer that you could then relay to your client.

Comment: +1. Consider putting that penultimate paragraph in bold.

Comment: This is misleading: "The GPL does not require that you GPL license any software that connects to MySQL". True, but it does if their program was linked with a GPLed connector ( http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ ). In comparison, the postgressql connector is BSD.

Comment: @jynus Just by connecting to a GPL database (or even a database that contains a schema of some other GPL'ed application) does not mean that the application that you are writing is under the GPL.  This says *nothing* about the library that you would need to use to link to the database. There is nothing about ConnectorJ in there and its quite possible the OP was using Drizzle (BSD) or the MariaDB connector (LGPL). But the act of connecting to the database does not entail a derivative work.

Comment: I quote from OP "Ok Can I sell my java application which will connects to a MYSQL data base uding JDBC connctor,without providing the sources.". I think it should be *plausible* that he is using the official MySQL JDBC connector, which is GPL, and has extra restrictions. Your answer is giving really bad general advice that can hurt future readers of the question. Additionally, I would never recomend contacting Oracle, as they could provide a biased answer ("yes, you have to pay us"), as they have done in the past many times to many of my clients.

Comment: Your edit fixes my problems, here is my upvote. My commitment to get this right is because I recently created a report on the legality of the MariaDB connector.

Comment: @jynus its always good to have the appropriate clarifications - and you were correct in that it leaves the nature of the libraries making the connection ambiguous. I admit to being spoiled from my days of old in perl where DBD::mysql was the only way to connect to MySQL and it was under a simple artistic license. One can forget that the connectors are licensed differently.  I really appreciate Mongo (under the AGPL) providing Apache licensed connectors (and making other promises - in writing even - for legal department appeasement).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the points that @MichealT made ...

If what you were doing was (hypothetically) a breach of the GPL, the License is actually between you and the MySQL copyright holders (i.e. Oracle).  Your customer has no right under law to demand that the license terms be enforced.  It would be up him to persuade Oracle to do that.  That means that Oracle's position on whether you are breaching the GPL is doubly pertinent.

Based on the facts as described, you may or may not be breaching the GPL.  It boils down to whether you are embedding MySQL in your product, or simply connecting to it.

And there's another way you could remedy this.  Buy a commercial license from Oracle to allow you to embed MySQL.  Then the GPL terms no longer apply.

(I am not a lawyer either ...)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, these aren't questions best posed to programmers. Almost all of the issues you raise are matters of contract and intellectual property law. Consult a local lawyer who is familiar with the software industry in your jurisdiction. If you don't have a written agreement with your client (very foolish), s/he will be able to advise you of the “defaults” in your jurisdiction a lot better than some random programmer on the Internet in a different state/country.

Comment: While it is true that it would be better to ask a lawyer, you would be hard pressed to find an IP lawyer willing to answer open-source licensing questions for free.  (OTOH, it sounds like the OP *needs* advice from a *qualified* professional ... and needs be prepared to pay for it!)

Comment: Who said anything about “free“? Once a client starts telling you that you have to hand over the source code, it becomes a matter of IP and contract law that depends on the jurisdiction. In *my* jurisdiction, ownership hinges on whether the job is considered a “work for hire” or not: in the absence of a contrary provision in a written agreement, the author (OP) would own the IP, not the client. *But*, the OP could be in Timbuctoo for all I know. Likely the law is different there. Consulting a local lawyer who knows the lay of the land seems like the prudent course of action.

Comment: Clearly the OP is trying to get free advice, by asking a question here.  But we clearly agree that he needs advice that he is NOT going to get for free.  And it sounds like the customer does too ... if he is trying to use GPL as leverage to get something he already has legal rights to!